# Finding a parameter such that two curves intersect orthogonally

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

For which value of $p$ do the curves $2x^{2} + 3y^{2} =1$ and $px^{2} + 6y^{2} =1$ intersect orthogonally?

(Options:) $1/3$, $4$, $3$, $2/3$.

I have calculated $\text{grad } f$ for these two curves

\begin{align}
\text{grad } f_1 &= (4x, 6y)\\
\text{grad } f_2 &= (2px,12y) .
\end{align}

How do I proceed next? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align}&\nabla f=(4x\,,\,6y)\\{}\\&\nabla g=(2px\,,\,12y)\end{align}$$

and now the curves are orthogonal at their intersection point $\;(a,b)\;$ (assuming they're differentiable there and etc.) iff

$$\nabla f(a,b)\cdot\nabla g(a,b)=0$$

Well, do the math now with the dot product *after* you find the curves' intersection point $\;(a,b)\;$...or otherwise.

Comment: i get $ px^{2] + 9y^{2} = 0 $ .Now how to get p ?

Comment: @tomb_raider $$2x^2+3y^2=1=px^2+6y^2\implies 4x^2=px^2$$ Now, check that $\;x=0\;$ cannot be a solution, so...

Comment: if p =4 is found out this way then why dotting grads

Comment: I've no idea. Either this question is connected to another one, or else some data is missing...I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For any function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and any $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $(\text{grad }f)(x_0, y_0)$ is orthogonal to the level set of $f$ through $(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: Please elaborate for this question

Comment: So, if level sets of $f$ and $g$ intersect at a point and are orthogonal, the level set of, e.g., $g$ must be tangent to $(\text{grad }f)(x_0, y_0)$, and hence both of these are orthogonal to $(\text{grad }g)(x_0, y_0)$. (We may want to restrict to points at which the gradient of neither function vanishes, for technical reasons.)

Comment: @I am not getting it .Please can you edit your answer and explain with more clarity

Comment: The argument in the previous comment says that in order for the curves to be orthogonal, we need the gradients $(\nabla f)(x_0, y_0), (\nabla g)(x_0, y_0)$ of the functions $f, g$ of which they are level sets to be orthogonal at the point(s) $(x_0, y_0)$ of intersection.

Comment: But i dotted them and i couldnot reach to anything except   $ px^{2] + 9y^{2} $= 0